# is Sharepoint and AnalysisServices required in BI Semantic Model?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, business-intelligence, reporting-services-2012

Im new to ReportModels. I'm was planning to test it on our new SSRS2012 and I just found out microsoft already depreciated this feature.

Furthur reading, it was replaced by BI Semantic Model. Long story short, I can seem to confirm if we need to setup Sharepoint for this to work.

1.) Is ShareportServices required for the BISM to work?
2.) do we also need Analysis Services for BISM to work too?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [this white paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj735264.aspx) will help you.

BISM refers to a couple of related technologies/tools, so the answers to your questions are not a simple yes/no.  As usual, it depends...

BI Semantic models can be in the form of individual Power Pivot models inside of Excel, shared in the same manner you would share any Excel file. They can also refer to Power Pivot models inside of SharePoint. Or they can refer to an SSAS Tabular model, which can be consumed with Power View inside of SharePoint or Power View in Excel (or just base Excel, or for that matter SSRS).

So if you are using Power Pivot in SharePoint or using Power View in SharePoint, then you will need SharePoint services.  If you are going to use SSAS Tabular, you will need SSAS.  If you are using Power Pivot in SharePoint, you need to install SSAS for Power Pivot and configure Power Pivot.